# Changing the password in Windows 7 hotspot

Tags: windows, windows-7, passwords, wireless-networking, hotspot

I turned my Windows 7 laptop into a wireless hotspot a while ago. Now I forgot the password I set. How can I see and change the password?

- I cannot see the network under Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks

Comment: Did you use the inbuilt Windows way or a third-party utility like `Connectify`?

Comment: Utility that shows wep/wpa keys to Wlan networks: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following command into a command prompt with admin rights (elevated command prompt):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyNet key=XXXX keyUsage=persistent
```

Change `MyNet` to the name of the network you would like to change the password for and replace the `XXXX` with your new password.

Comment: What does it do? Can you expand upon this answer?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem in creating a new hot-spot with new password?

The reason why you do not see the network under Control Panel\Network and Internet\Manage Wireless Networks is either you deleted it or used another profile?

[Turn Your Windows 7 PC Into a Wireless Hotspot](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)